# How can we analytically solve this max-sum-min problem?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

Let $I$ be a finite set, and $A_{ij},B_{ij},x_i,y_j\ge0$. I want to find the choice of $x_i,y_j$ maximizing $$\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in J}A_{ij}\min\left(x_i,B_{ij}y_j\right)\tag1$$ subject to $$\sum_{i\in I}x_i=\sum_{j\in I}y_j=1\tag2.$$ As [discussed on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3340373/47771), the feasible region is divided into polygons such that the objective function is linear on each interval. With this approach we end with a finite number of candidate points (the vertices) we need to compute the maximum of.

However, I need to find a closed form expression for $x_i,y_j$. Are we able to achieve this? If not, are we at least able to find a (sharp) lower bound for $(1)$ for which it is easier to obtain a closed form maximizer?

Comment: Standard trick is to introduce variables $z_{ij}$ with $z_{ij}\leq x_i$ and $z_{ij}\leq B_{ij}y_j$, and to maximize:$$\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in J}A_{ij}z_{ij}.$$

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thank you for your comment. I guess we're enforcing $z_{ij}\ge0$, right? It's been a while since I thought about linear optimization, but I need to implement a solver (with as less overhead as possible) for the problem. Do you have a good reference at hand? (I guess there's no hope for a closed form solution, right?)

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Oh, and while I see the formal point in bringing the problem into some kind of "normal" or "standard" form by introducing $z_{ij}$, this should produce a significant overhead. Is there a more direct approach for the special shape of the problem?

Comment: Since $A_{ij}\geq 0$, you don't need to enforce $z_{ij}\geq 0$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Would be great if you could (briefly) elaborate on the other questions in my comments.

Comment: I don't have much to say.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Can we use a similar trick here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3409501/47771?

Comment: I don't think so. The objective function there is not (piecewise) linear.